# How can one make global variables in R visible to a C function called from within R?

Tags: r, c

I am using the function `int2` in R package [`rmutil`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmutil/index.html) for numerical computation of double integrals. The function I want to integrate is a [bivariate normal probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case):

[image]

which has two variables (x and y) and five parameters. If I let, say, mu_x=mu_y=0, sigma_x=sigma_y=1, and rho=0.5, I can code the function in R as follows:

`f1 <- function(x, y) 1/(sqrt(3) * pi) * exp(-2/3 * (x^2 + y^2 - x*y))`

I then integrate the function using `int2` as follows:

```
rmutil::int2(f1, a=c(-Inf,-Inf), b=c(Inf,Inf))
[1] 0.9999998
```

Good: exact value of the integral is 1.

However, I need to be able to integrate the above function repeatedly for different values of the aforementioned parameters. I tried to do this as follows:

```
bvtnorm <- function(x, y, mu_x = 0, mu_y = 0, sigma_x = 1, sigma_y = 1, rho = 0.5) {
  function(x, y) 
  1 / (2 * pi * sigma_x * sigma_y * sqrt(1 - rho ^ 2)) * 
    exp(- 1 / (2 * (1 - rho ^ 2)) * ((x - mu_x) / sigma_x) ^ 2 + 
          ((y - mu_y) / sigma_y) ^ 2 - 2 * rho * (x - mu_x) * (y - mu_y) / 
          (sigma_x * sigma_y))
}
f2 <- bvtnorm(x, y)
```

We can verify that `f1` and `f2` return the same values for the same `x` and `y` inputs:

```
f1(1, 1)
[1] 0.0943539
f2(1, 1)
[1] 0.0943539
```

However, when I run `int2` on `f2`, as follows, it fails to integrate:

```
rmutil::int2(f2, a=c(-Inf,-Inf), b=c(Inf,Inf))
[1] NaN
```

I defined the parameter variables to send to `bvtnorm` globally using `mu_x <<- 0`, `mu_y <<- 0`, `sigma_x <<- 1`, `sigma_y <<- 1`, and `rho <<- 0.5`, so that their values would be visible within the `rmutil::int2` function environment, but this didn't work. When I examined the source code for `rmutil::int2` I discovered the likely reason: within this function, there is a call to a C function using `.C`. I presume that even global variables in R are not visible to C functions called within R, and thus the C function will fail to evaluate `bvtnorm` (via `f2`, via `rmutil::int2`) because `mu_x`, `mu_y`, etc. are unknown. Thus my question is:

*Is there any way to make variables in an R environment visible to C functions called from within R?*

I presume that one possible solution would be to modify the `rmutil::int2` function and the C function it calls to send the parameters mu_x, mu_y, etc. to the C function. However, I would like to avoid modifying someone else's code in an existing CRAN package if possible.

Comment: Is the C program supposed to be a standalone executable?  If that's the case you would have to send values to it as command line arguments.

Comment: I don't think so; the C program just contains three functions. This is it: https://github.com/cran/rmutil/blob/master/src/romberg.c

Comment: In your definition of `bvtnorm`, you should `force()` each of your arguments that you want bound to the resulting function environment. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/function-factories.html#forcing-evaluation

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I had in the meantime come up with a much untidier solution, which was to use `paste0` to concatenate parameter names within the rest of the `function(x, y)` code and put the resulting character `char` inside `eval(parse(text = char))`

Comment: I thought I would just add that `cubature::adaptIntegrate` turns out to be a faster and more accurate method for computing double integrals in R than `rmutil::int2`.